# PHP / MySQL / AJAX - Update multiple data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

How to update multiple data using AJAX ?

**Example :**

> TableA
>
> id : 1, 2
>
> name : Jack, John

It's only working with id **1**, when I am trying to edit name for id **2** it's not working.

I have try with this code but failed.

HTML/PHP :

```
...

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo'    
    <form class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_user" id="id_user" data-user="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_status" id="id_status" data-status="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'">
        <button type="submit" id="likestatus" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
        </form>
    ';
    }
```

AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#likestatus").click(function(){
    var id_user=$("#id_user").data("user");
    var id_status=$("#id_status").data("status");
        $.ajax({
        url:'status/like-status.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:{
            id_user:id_user,
            id_status:id_status
            },
            success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that ids should be unique, but in the loop you create elements with same id.

Use `this` in the event handler to find the siblings of the button that has been clicked - closest returns the parent of type form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var id_user=$form.find('[name="id_user"]').data("user");
        var id_status=$form.find('[name="id_status"]').data("status");
            $.ajax({
            url:'status/like-status.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                id_user:id_user,
                id_status:id_status
                },
                success:function(response){
                alert(response);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

You might want to use your own class instead of `.btn-primary` because this affects all buttons on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the incomplete PHP, it appears as if you're not assigning to `$ruser` within your loop. This would mean you're always posting the same id to `like-status.php`.

*PS: Would've posted as comment, but I can't.*

Answer (score 1):

You're using the id's multiple times. Thus your query for `var id_user=$("#id_user").data("user");` always finds the first input field on the page. You should avoid using the same id multiple times on one page (see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)).

You may subscribe to the [jQuery `submit` event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) of the form and then search for the input fields within that form, to properly extract the `id_user` and `status_user` values. For that you have to add an appropriate event listener to the `<form>` element. To find the form I would recommend adding a css-class like `like-status-form`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // We're attaching a submit-event listener to every element with the css class "like-status-form"
    $(".like-status-form").submit(function(event){
       // Form get's submitted
       // Prevent that the Browser reloads the page
       event.preventDefault();

       // Extract the user id and status from the form element (=== $(this))
       var id_user = $(this).find('[name="id_user"]').data('user');
       var id_status = $(this).find('[name="id_status"]').data('status');

       // TODO Perform AJAX Call here
    });
});
```

To detect the form elements one can use the jQuery [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Find a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/07yzf8k1/

Answer (score 1):

Make your ID unique so make them dynamic

```
 <?php

 $counter = 0;

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $counter++;

    echo'    
    <form class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userid_$counter" data-user="'.$ruser['id'].'" value="'.$ruser['id'].'">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_status" id="status_$counter" data-status="'.$rtimeline['id'].'" value="'.$rtimeline['id'].'">
        <button type="submit" id="likestatus_$counter" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
        </form>
    ';
    }
?>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="likestatus_"]').on('click',function(){
         var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
    var id_user=$("#user_"+index).data("user");
    var id_status=$("#status_"+index).data("status");
        $.ajax({
        url:'status/like-status.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:{
            id_user:id_user,
            id_status:id_status
            },
            success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```